# Which function to used for virdis palette?

Tags: r

Is there a way to use "virdis" palette with the following function?

`colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n, name)`

Comment: The `viridis` package includes a function `viridis_pal()` which you can use in the same way as `colorRampPalette()`. You do not need to nest another function inside it as you would with the brewer palette. For example `viridis_pal()(10)` would give you a ramp of 10 viridis colors, with all default options.

Comment: Thank you it worked!